# Convert sql data into csv file

Tags: objective-c, sql, ios, cocoa-touch, csv

I have one sql file with 5 columns and has data into it. How can i convert this sql file data into csv file and store that csv file in the device.

Comment: Um....by reading each of the columns row by row and outputting them with commas in between them?  Which part are you having trouble with...?

Comment: So that would give me very big string so should i write this string in a file by converting it in to NSdata. And save the file as .csv extension.

Comment: That is the general idea...as long as you don't have so much data that you can't fit it all into memory at once.  In that case, you will have to do it in chunks.

Comment: As you read each row, write the output to file, continue to append for each row. Then you do not have a huge string in memory.